# I need to create a web-application in java which consumes SOAP based .Net web service. For this which tool and framework I shall use?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, soap

Things to be considered are:

- Open Source
- API for generating a SOAP request from a WSDL file. (I have done some samples with AXIS 2.)
- Easy implementation ( like PLAY/GRAILS frameworks) to optimize developer productivity.

I have found this link : http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/web-services-using-play/
which sounds easier to build but not sure about the complexities when the requirement changes over a period of time.

As of now there will not be any data base to store any details. But the requirement might change once the prototype is finished.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to program or not?

Comment: What have you tried?  Would Eclipse's JEE setup get it done for you?  Generally you can add a Web Service Client to a project (File > New > Other... > Web Service Client), specify a WSDL and be off to the races.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring web services is pretty nice, and has an easy to use client layer.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html

There's configuration work you have to do in spring XML or java based config, but once that's done, it's pretty easy:

```
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(msgText));
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);               
webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(
            uri,
            source,
            result);
```

The uri parameter is optional (there's a method where you don't need it) if you want to send the message to the default URI for the webServiceTemplate object.

The particular example deals with straight xml, but there's more advanced features for marshalling/unmarshalling objects, security, etc...

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have found that, we can easily create SOAP based web client using all the three frameworks (PLAY/GRAILS/SPRING). * Play - http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/web-services-using-play/  * Grails - http://grails.org/plugin/ws-client * Spring - http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html

Comment: Thanks Matt I have decided to go ahead with Spring WebServiceTemplate :)

Comment: I am not able to use CXF, AXIS 2 and Java-WS it says WSDL is not valid. So I tried with axis and generated the proxies and I am using this with Spring MVC. It works .... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) and [ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/index.html).